WireMock cannot handle complex form parameter names
WireMock standalone version 3.5.2
I'm trying to mock a form request with complex form parameter names. For example:
settings[schedule][delay]=7&settings[schedule][interval]=weekly
In the response template, I reference the form values as:
"interval": "{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{form.settings[schedule][interval]}}"
I was expecting to have the value weekly in the response, but I got an error instead:

{
"cause1":"wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@19e6ab7c:129:70: could not find helper: 'form.settings'\n        "interval": "{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{form.settings[schedule][interval]}}",\n                                                                      ^\n",
"servlet":"com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet-15200332",
"cause0":"wiremock.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@19e6ab7c:129:70: could not find helper: 'form.settings'\n        "interval": "{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{form.settings[schedule][interval]}}",\n                                                                      ^\n",
"message":"wiremock.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@19e6ab7c:129:70: could not find helper: 'form.settings'\n        "interval": "{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{form.settings[schedule][interval]}}",\n                                                                      ^\n",
"url":"/path",
"status":"500"
}

I tried URL encoding the form parameter name in the template but got a similar error.
Is there any way I can make this work?
Thanks.

I think [] are used for ID lookups in handlebars so this is being parsed as a language operator. To get around this we can use the lookup helper.  In the response template try this:
{
  "interval": "{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{lookup form 'settings[schedule][interval]'}}"
}

Starting WireMock and then sending a request like the following:
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/form-example \
   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
   -d "settings[schedule][delay]=7&settings[schedule][interval]=weekly" 

Returns a response like this:
{
  "interval": "weekly"
}

